# How to Invert a Monotonic Function that Contains an Integral?

Tags: integration, inverse

Consider $y=b(c)$ where the function $b$ is continuous, strictly increasing in its argument. So that there exists an inverse. However, $b(c)$ is quite complicated and has an integral:
$$
b(c) = \int_{c}^{1} g(x) dx ~ .
$$

The problem is to obtain the inverse of $b$:

$$
 c = b^{-1}(y)
$$

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a closed-form for the inverse function?

Comment: Do you believe there's no closed solution? Even so, i would be happy to know how to solve similar problems when there's a closed form solution

Comment: Even for functions that don't involve an integral, it's rather rare to have a closed-form inverse function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can say is that $b^{-1}(y) = c$ is a solution of the initial value ODE problem
$$ \eqalign{g(c)\; c' &= -1\cr
 c(0) &= 1 \cr}$$
As mentioned in the comments, it's unlikely to have closed-form explicit solutions.  But, given good numerical ODE solvers, this may be a good way to 
get numerical results.

EDIT: As requested, here's an example.  I'll use Maple, and
 take $g(x) = \dfrac{2 + \sin(x)}{1+x^2}$.

```
g:= x -> (2+sin(x))/(1+x^2):
S:= dsolve({g(c(y)) * diff(c(y),y) = -1, c(0) = 1},c(y), numeric):
S(1);
```

$$[y = 1., c(y) = .428444801994959]$$

```
plots[odeplot](S, [y,c(y)],y=-1.5..4);
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It would be great if you could expand a little bit on your last comment about numerical solutions... ;)